# Definition of the differentiability of a map at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm reading the book "Multivariate Calculus and Geometry", written by Seán Dineen, and there's the following definition of the differentiability of a map at a point:

> Let $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, $U$ open, and let
>   $X_0\in U$. We say $F$ is differentiable at $X_0\in U$ if there exists
>   a function $A:U\to M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ which is continuous at $X_0$
>   such that $F(X)=F(X_0)+A(X)(X-X_0)$ for all $X\in U$.

My question is: why should U be an open set? I can't understand the need to make this restriction since I can't see any problems when considering closed sets.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason open sets are considered is because derivatives are certain limits, and in open sets you can consider limits from all possible directions. However, you can say that if $A\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is *any* set, then $f\colon A \to \Bbb R^k$ is smooth if there is a smooth (our previous notion) extension $\widetilde{f}\colon U \to \Bbb R^k$, where $U$ is an open set containing $A$. This is done, for example, in Guillemin & Pollack's Differential Topology book.

Comment: When is a map $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^k$ considered smooth? I started to study multivariate calculus today, so I don't know what that term means.

Comment: The term "smooth" is synonymous for "differentiable" or "of class $C^\infty$", depending on context.

Comment: Just one more question: in this context and looking at that definition of derivative, can I say that $F'(X)$ is the derivative of $F(X)$ respect to $X$? Or is this terminology only used in single variable calculus?

Comment: You can say that $F'(X)$ is the total derivative of $F$, at the point $X$. This terminology is used when discussing partial derivatives, only. At the worst case, if $F\colon \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^k$, you can decompose the total derivative into the direct sum of "fat" partial derivatives, as in ${\sf D}F(x,y)(h,k) = {\sf D}_xF(x,y)(h) + {\sf D}_yF(x,y)(k)$, which is useful to understand the implicit function theorem.

Comment: I honestly didn't understand your question very well, but today I imagined that the author put that restriction to avoid isolated points, since any function is continuous in isolated points, consequently any function has derivatives in those points. Do you think that's right?